# Two dimensional array element traverse

Tags: c, arrays

I was asked a question in an interview. It was unknown to me. I have done some googling but can't find the exact answer. The question was:

Which one is more efficient? Is there any difference between *option1* and *option2* in performance?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[50][50];
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<50; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]); // option1
            printf("%d ", arr[j][i]); // option2
        }
    }

}
```

Is there any performance difference between them? If there is a difference, then which one is faster in execution? And why?

Comment: Have you done any experiments ?

Comment: in case of the array size being `[50][50]`, there seems to be no difference. However, theoretically, if the array is _big enough_, the second approach can cause cache miss.

Comment: read `how arrays are stored in memory`, and then `what locality of reference is`.